# Check if client.users() / User ID has specific role name

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js

I would like to check if a client.users() has a specific rolename. I am not searching for some solutions like msg.member.roles.find(), I need a solution where I can use client.users() or insert the user id

```
if (client.users().role.find("name", "rolename"))
{
  //something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method `Client.users()`. There is, however, a property [`Client.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users). But, the latter is a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)s, and only [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)s have roles.

You'll have to [iterate through](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) each of the client's guilds ([`Client.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds)), then through each member ([`Guild.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members)), and attempt to find the role you're looking for ([`Collection.find`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find)).

Example:

```js
for ([guildID, guild] of client.guilds) {
  for ([memberID, member] of guild.members) {
    if (member.roles.find(role => role.name === 'name')) {
      // Do something to this member.
    }
  }
}
```

If you're looking for just one member, you don't have to iterate through the members.

```js
for ([guildID, guild] of client.guilds) {
  const member = guild.members.get('someID');
  if (!member) continue;

  // Do something to this member.
}
```